# Aligning defined section title correctly

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titles

This is a MWE of a section title I'm trying to define in a large project.

```
\documentclass[a2,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{tikz}

% Blue section, large, text on next line.
\def\Lsect#1{\noindent\hbox to \hsize{\large\color{blue} #1}\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\Lsect{This is a title}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I've stripped the LaTeX file of every non-essential line to reproduce the issue (I'm not sure why `tikz` needs to be there though)

I need to have the title correctly aligned to the left and I just can't figure out how to do that, I've tried every modification the the definition I could think of.

Comment: `\def\Lsect#1{\noindent\hbox to \hsize{\large\color{blue} #1\hfill}\bigskip}` or `\def\Lsect#1{\noindent\hbox{\large\color{blue} #1}\bigskip}`

Comment: The second line is not what I need since the text is written on the same line as the title. The first one works perfectly, would you mind putting is as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify an hbox to a certain size, TeX will try to fit the contents to that size. If want to align the content to a certain direction, try one of the following rubber lengths:

- `\hfil`, `\hfill` or `\hfilll`
- `\hss`

---

```
\documentclass[a2,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Blue section, large, text on next line.
\def\Lsect#1{\noindent\hbox to \hsize{\large\color{blue} #1\hfil}\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\Lsect{This is a title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

> [image]